# C++ Asynchronous Timer (STL/Boost) that does not spawn a thread

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, timer, stl

is there a mechanism already implemented in the standard library or in boost which allows me to create asynchronous timers that don't spawn a own thread which also can be cancelled?

I need a mechanism that allows me to post a callback function to be called on an object in a list (the list is about 40k entries) every 10 minutes. If the object in the list receives a value update, the timer has to be restarted.

My implementation would be a linked list in which I insert an object with a timestamp and a thread which executes the function for every object when its time has come. But it seems to be a too common problem for nothing to exist in that direction.

Thanks

Comment: boost [deadline_timer::async_wait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/async_wait.html) doesn't spawn its own thread, it uses the thread/threadpool that you supply.

Comment: Can one restart the async_waits?

Comment: Yes you can restart the timer.  Both `cancel ()` and `expires_from_now ()` will call any outstanding callback with the "operation aborted" error code.

Comment: Awesome, I'll test that. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Cubbi I think that's actually platform dependent. I know some ASIO services spawn threads on Win32 e.g.

Comment: Why do you require "no threads"? It's not like you get a thread per timer. Iffff the implementation uses a thread, it will be one for all your timer objects (likely more). Could be dependent on the presense of BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP etc.